# Insert/Delete in O(1) time in HashMaps with millions of objects (with distinct keys)?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I know that insert/delete works in O(1) time with Java HashMaps.

But is it still the fastest data structure if I have over a million objects (with distinct keys - i.e. each object has a unique key) in my HashMap?

Comment: The number of objects isn't really the concern, it's the distribution of key hashcodes. The constant `1` in `O(1)` is not insignificant with `HashMap`; so saying it's the fastest data structure is problematic (although it may well the expected case).

Comment: it depends on the collisions of the hash function. technically, the performance is O(k), where k is the number of collisions. While collisions are very rare for a good hash function, therefore we usually think it is O(1).

Comment: Which data structure would you recommend then to deal with over a million objects (target: fast insert/remove and iteration)? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: If the keys are ensured to be distinct, then there should be no collisions, right? @JunbangHuang

Comment: @YaleBD That's impossible to answer without knowing more about the keys, and it's the hash code of the keys that you need to worry about. What kind of objects are these?

Comment: These are my agents (in a simulation), look like: ` class Agent {
  int key; int age; State state; double timeDeath; int district;  boolean willProgress, isVaccinated; String vName; ...
 
  Agent (AgeGroup ageGroup, int ageInWeeks) { 
  this.key = Model.currentAgentKey; // key is assigned here for the HashMap
  ...
 }
 ...
}` @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @YaleBD yes. but it is very hard to do. more technically, it depends. if our data is not big enough, usually collision will not happen. but it is very very big. there surely will be collision. the thing is hashmap are designed to deal with collisions. there are algorithm to deal with this problem. for more about the resolution, you can read this one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution

Comment: @YaleBD Wrong. It depends on the `hashCode()`s of the keys, not the keys themselves, and then on what further hashing the `HashMap` does with the hash codes.

Comment: Please post the class of the key

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - profile your code!

The average performance of `HashMap` insertion and deletion scales as `O(1)` (assuming you have a sound hashCode() method on the keys<sup>1</sup>) until you start running into 2nd-order memory effects:

- The larger the heap is, the longer it takes to garbage collect.  Generally, the factors that impact most are the number and size of non-garbage objects.  A big enough `HashMap` will do that ...
- Your hardware has a limited amount of physical memory.  If your JVM's memory demand grows beyond that, the host OS will "swap" memory pages between RAM and disk.  A big enough `HashMap` will do that ... if your heap size is bigger than the amount of physical RAM available to the JVM process.
- There are memory effects that are due to the sizes of your processors' memory cache and TLB cache sizes.  Basically, if the processors "demand" in reading and writing memory is too great, the memory system becomes the bottleneck.  These effects can be exacerbated by a large heap and highly non-localized access patterns.  (And running the GC!)

There is also a limit of about 2^31 on the size of a `HashMap`'s primary hash array.  So if you have more than about 2^31 / 0.75 entries, the performance of the current `HashMap` implementation theoretically `O(N)`.  However, we are talking **billions** of entries, and the 2nd order memory effects will be impacting on performance well before then.

---

<sup>1 - If your keys have a poor `hashCode()` function, then you may find that you get a significant proportion of the keys hash to the same code.  If that happens, lookup, insert and delete performance for those keys will be either `O(logN)` or `O(N)` ... depending on the key's type, and your Java version.  In this case, `N` is the number keys in the table with the same hashcode as the one you are looking up, etc.</sup>

---

Is `HashMap` the fastest data structure for your use-case?

- It is hard to say without more details of your use-case.
- It is hard to say without understanding how much time and effort you are prepared to put into the problem.  (If you put in enough coding effort, you could almost certainly trim a few percent off.  Maybe a lot more.  `HashMap` is general purpose.)
- It is hard to say without you (first!) doing a proper performance analysis.

For example, you first need to be sure that the `HashMap` really is the cause of your performance problems.  Sure, you >>think<< it is, but have you actually profiled your code to find out?  Until you do this, you risk wasting your time on optimizing something that isn't the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

So HashMaps will have an O(1) insert/delete even for a huge number of objects. The problem for a huge amount of data is the space. For a million entries you may be fine with in memory.

Java has a default load factor of .75 for a HashMap, meaning that a HashMap would need 1.33 million slots to support this map. If you can support this in memory, it's all fine. Even if you can't hold this all in memory, you'd probably still want to use HashMaps, perhaps a [Distributed HashMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table).

As far as Big-O time goes, this refers to the worst case complexity. The only time the analysis of Big-O time is really useful is as data sizes get larger and larger. If you were working with a really small data set, O(5n+10) would not be the same as O(n). The reason that constant time ( O(1) ) time is so valuable is because it means that the time doesn't depend on the size of the data set. Therefore, for a large data set like the one you're describing, a HashMap would be an excellent option due to its constant time insert/delete.

Comment: Thank you.. I was expecting faster (reduced runtime), and so switched from an ArrayList to a HashMap. But looks like they both need the same amount of time for this case (I needed many insert/delete and one iterate for each of the 22 HashMaps, for a total of ~1000 times). @gwcoderguy

Comment: If you're not mapping anything, may I suggest using a [HashSet](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashset_class.htm) which is basically a HashMap, but not mapping one thing to another.

Comment: The delete should certainly be faster in a HashSet or HashMap than an array list as you can lookup the item to be deleted far faster. The insertion should be somewhat faster in an arraylist as no calculation or iteration needs to be done (unless you have hit the max size of the array). Iteration should be somewhat faster in the arraylist as well, because the map must iterate over the empty slots in the map as well.

If you truly want to be sure, follow the advice of Stephen C and profile your code!

Comment: Thank you! The HashMap actually gave me > 10x improvements in runtime! So from 10mins 26 secs now I got it down to 50 secs - this seems wonderful! will try HashSet later... @gwcoderguy